# Determine whether the ODE is linear or not

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This practice exam questions asks:

Determine whether the following Ordinary Differential Equation is linear or not:

$y' = f(t,y),$ $with$  $y({t_0}) = {y_0}$.

I feel that not enough information is given about the given ODE? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is $f$? Kinda depends on that

Comment: $f$ was never given in the question.

Comment: Then your answer is correct, there is not enough information. With for example $f(t,y)=y$ it would be linear, with $f(t,y)=y^2$ it would be non-linear.

Comment: Are you sure there's no additional information anywhere on the exam materials? This looks like a really weird way to confuse the students

Comment: Yes I am sure, but my lecturer can be confusing at times.